# When to fill tires with air

Tags: tires

My tire psi levels are at 30 for each tire. I drive a GMC Terrain. When should I start to think about putting air in them?

Answer (score 6):

Check the pressure with a pressure gauge regularly, when it drops 2 psi below the recommended pressure, top them up. Always measure the pressure when the tires are cold (car's been sitting for a few hours in the shade).

There's a sticker, either in the glove box or on the driver door pillar that says what the recommended pressure is. Keep it within 2 psi.

Comment: I'd check the pressure rating on the tyres themselves first, they can differ from the recommended pressure for the original tyres. But good point concerning measuring the tyres when they're at ambient temperature.

Comment: @Bart - Even with what is on the tire's sidewall, you should follow the manufacturer's recommended tire pressure guidance found on the vehicle. What is on the tire's sidewall is a *maximum* tire pressure you should not exceed. The only reason I can think of *not* following the recommended pressure is if you are using LT tires on a pickup truck. Other than that, *always follow the manufacturer's recommendation*.

Comment: If you can't check them while they're cold, I've found that driving around adds about 2-3 PSI, so I fill them up to 2-3 PSI over what is on the sticker.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask specific timing for filling air into tyre as per your application but generally preferable every week. Check your tire pressure and ,if required, fill it in cold conditions common in the morning when first starting a trip.